# send vue.js data object to backend using axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I need to send full data object of Vue Instance to back-end via axios. This is my code.

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#el',
    delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
    data: {
        brand: 0,
        model: 0,
        country: "europe",
    },
    created: function () {
    },
    updated: function () {
        axios.post('http://localhost:81/lnt/public/member/car_result', {data: this.data})
            .then(function (response) {

        });
    }
});
```

When I `console.log(this.data);` I'm getting an undefined output
And when I try

```
axios.post('http://localhost:81/lnt/public/member/car_result', {brand: this.brand})
```

I can send brand but need to send whole data array at once

Comment: Ok, so, instead of `{data: this.data}` just use `this.data`...that should do the trick :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the whole `data` object you have to use `this.$data`

```
updated: function () {
   axios.post('http://localhost:81/lnt/public/member/car_result', {data: this.$data})
   .then(function (response) {
       //do something
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so so much bro you saved my day

Comment: No problem - I am glad, that I could help :-)